# Details from a subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have to get the details from a selection inside the tase table, but cant seem to find out how to make that join, the initial info I get it from this query.

```
select /*+ Parallel 4*/
extract(month from h.ts1) mes, h.Email,
        count(case when h.id in ('3','4') then 1 end)  A,
        count(case when h.id not in ('3','4') and h.id is not null  then 1 end) F,
        count(case when h.id is null then 1 end)  N,
count(1) Total
from tbl1  h
where h.id2 = '21'
and h.ts2 >= timestamp '2016-12-01 00:00:00'
and h.ts2 < timestamp '2017-01-01 00:00:00'
and h.ts1 >= timestamp '2016-12-01 00:00:00'
and h.ts1 < timestamp '2017-01-01 00:00:00'
group by 
extract(month from h.ts1),
h.Email
```

Get this table:

```
MES  EMAIL              A   F   N   Total
__  ______________      __  __  __  __
12  NA@email.COM        16  9   315 340
12  AIR@email.COM       36  0   178 214
12  XGAD@email.COM      35  0   4   39
12  TEST@email.COM      0   0   35  35
12  E@email2.com        0   0   22  22
12  VI@email.COM        8   0   11  19
12  CL@email.NET        0   0   17  17
12  RH.GCM@email.COM    0   0   16  16
12  MA@email.COM        2   0   14  16
```

And my goal is to get the Email from that selection match the orginal table
and give me more details.

I've been trying this query:

```
select 
b.mes, h.email, h.ts3, h.detail1, h.detail_2
from tbl1 h     
inner join (
select /*+ Parallel 4*/
extract(month from h.ts1) mes, h.Email,
        count(case when h.id in ('3','4') then 1 end)  A,
        count(case when h.id not in ('3','4') and h.id is not null  then 1 end) F,
        count(case when h.id is null then 1 end)  N,
count(1) Total
from tbl1  h
where h.id2 = '21'
and h.ts2 >= timestamp '2016-12-01 00:00:00'
and h.ts2 < timestamp '2017-01-01 00:00:00'
and h.ts1 >= timestamp '2016-12-01 00:00:00'
and h.ts1 < timestamp '2017-01-01 00:00:00'
group by 
extract(month from h.ts1),
h.Email) b
on b.email=h.email
order by 1 desc;
```

but it sends me an error:

```
Error starting at line :  in command -
h.ts1
Error report -
Unknown Command
```

I expect results like this:

```
MES  EMAIL              DETAIL1 DETAIL2     A   F   N   Total
__  ______________      ______  ________    __  __  __  __
12  NA@email.COM        rfeQR   WerdST      16  9   315 340
12  AIR@email.COM       ewfrT   qweQWq      36  0   178 214
12  XGAD@email.COM      qweeQ   qwedqw      35  0   4   39
12  TEST@email.COM      12DQD   DEfewE      0   0   35  35
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't see the connection to `h.live_overview_3` - what is that? In any case, the query you posted (the full one) should fail, at least, due to the `order by` clause. You say `order by 6` which means by the sixth column, but you are only selecting five columns. It is also unclear how you would get the "expected result" from that query, since you are only selecting `mes` from the subquery, not the other columns it calculates.

Comment: Yeah thakn let me fix the question, and want them connected trhough mail

Comment: You are using same alias `h` in both inner query and outer query, which is leading to error I suppose. Please give different alias for table `tbl1 ` in outer query, say `h2`.